# How to include all of my child associations in my rails api json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to output my entire object as a json, but it isn't rendering the associations.

My object is loaded using includes like this:

```
 School.includes(head_office: [class_rooms: [desks: [:chair]]])
      .find_by(school_id: 1)
```

Now my api is currently only responding with the school as json.

I can't seem to figure out the syntax to get all these nested associations included in the expanded json.

How can I do this?

I tried this so far and I am getting an error:

```
 render json: school.to_json(include: [head_office: [:class_rooms]])
```

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Answer (score 1):

Use should do something like this:

```
render json: school.to_json(include: { head_office: { include :class_rooms } })
```

Comment: `render json: school.to_json(inlcude: :head_office)` works. The include part for chosen fields seems to be syntactically incorrect.